# Вытянуть данные из UPDATE в триггер BEFORE UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли вытянуть данные из UPDATE, чтобы в триггере ими оперировать?

Comment: используйте OLD.col_name чтобы получить старое значение. подробнее - тут https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: тогда нужно будет изменить триггер с BEFORE на AFTER так я понимаю. После изменения смотреть старое значение и уже что-то делать.  Суть в том чтобы посмотреть значения в UPDATE до изменения

Comment: возможно, я не так читаю доки, но именно BEFORE UPDATE и позволяет использовать old.value. вы смотрели примеры использования?

Comment: @ЮрийВас А Вы попробуйте описывать задачу, а не то, как Вы собрались её решать... может, Вы вообще не тем путём идёте.

Comment: @Akina При перед UPDATE поля должна протий проверка на корректность данных. После положительной проверки вызывается UPDATE в другой таблице с данными триггера UPDATE. Вот такой алгоритм

Comment: @ЮрийВас покажите код. без этого что-то вразумительное ответить невозможно

Comment: Триггера BEFORE и AFTER отличаются только моментом _до_ записи на диск это происходит или _после_. Так же в триггере на before insert будет не доступно значение автоинкрементного id. Других отличий нет. В обоих случаях вам доступны полные наборы данных как они выглядели до операции update (в OLD) и как они будут выглядеть после (в NEW). В триггере BEFORE, так как запись на диск еще не произошла вы можете менять значения в NEW

Comment: так что вы можете производить любые проверки, какие захотите. причем практически в любом из видов триггера. так же вы можете вызывать update другой таблицы в обоих видах триггера, за очень редкими исключениями изменения первичного ключа и зависимости изменяемой дополнительно таблицы от него

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis да я разобрался благодаря вашей ссылки. спасибо большое. Коментарии других мне тоже помогли.